How to find the keycodes for remapping Control and Super keys using xmodmap on X11
I am trying to swap my Super_L and Control_L keys on my keyboard. I determine the keycodes for remapping these keys using xev, showkey, and xmodmap itself. They provide me different keycodes but none of them works when I use them to swap the functionality.
I have gone through other posts (e.g. this) and have tried what has been suggested already. But, nothing has worked out for me. Please help me determine why my key swap is not working.
Things to note -

key swap is working fine for other standard keys.
key code are swapped when inspected after remap in xev or xmodmap but their function do not change.
I have installed i3wm on Ubuntu 24.04.
I have a Logitech MX Keys Mini keyboard connected to my system over bluetooth.

Keycodes without any remapping:
$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i super                                                                                                                                 
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

$ xmodmap -pke | grep -i control                                                                                  
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R

$ xev | awk -F'[ )]+' '/^KeyPress/ { a[NR+2] } NR in a { printf "%-3s %s\n", $5, $8 }'
37  Control_L
133 Super_L

$ sudo showkey                                                                          kb mode was ?UNKNOWN?
[ if you are trying this under X, it might not work
since the X server is also reading /dev/console ]

press any key (program terminates 10s after last keypress)...
keycode  28 release
keycode  29 press       --------- corresponds to Control_L
keycode  29 release     --------- corresponds to Control_L
keycode 125 press       --------- corresponds to Super_L
keycode 125 release     --------- corresponds to Super_L


For changing the functionality of the modifier keys (shift, lock, control, alt, numlock, etc.), we first need to clear the modifier map followed by assigning the keycodes to the modifiers followed by adding the modifier map back.
You can check your modifier map by running xmodmap -pm.
e.g.-
> xmodmap -pke | grep -i control
keycode  37 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
keycode 105 = Control_R NoSymbol Control_R

> xmodmap -pke | grep -i super
keycode 133 = Super_L NoSymbol Super_L
keycode 134 = Super_R NoSymbol Super_R
keycode 206 = NoSymbol Super_L NoSymbol Super_L

You can find the keycodes mapped to the modifier keys by running xmodmap -pke | grep <modifier>.
e.g.-
xmodmap -pm
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Alt_L (0xcc),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3        ISO_Level5_Shift (0xcb)
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c)


After looking at the values, you can clear modifier map, assign modifiers keys to keycodes, and add the modifier map back.
e.g. -
clear mod4
clear control
keycode 37 = Super_L
keycode 133 = Control_L
add mod4 = Super_L
add control = Control_L

Load the new configuration by running - xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap.
